# Delete a listview entry

Tags: android, sql, listview

My problem is, that in the ListView/Database only the topmost "comment" gets deleted, but I want, that the "comment" which are pressed get deleted.

```
@Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);




        this.getListView().setClickable(true);
           this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "postion: " +    getListView().getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is the problem, namely at getcount > 0.

```
                    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
                    Comment comment = null;
                    if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                        comment = (Comment) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                        datasource.deleteComment(comment);
                        adapter.remove(comment);
                      }
                    return;
                }});
           }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, tips and that you were honest with me!!

Comment: You're welcome, but click the check mark inside an answer to accept it. Very few answers will be perfect, so accept the ones that are closest or most helpful. Good luck with your finished app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using getItem(0) is always going to remove the first item in the adapter (and therefore the listview).

If you want to remove the items when they are clicked, in onItemClick, use the following code.

```
Comment comment = (Comment) adapter.getItem(position);
datasource.deleteComment(comment);
adapter.remove(comment);
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: It works perfect, but i want additional if I click on a listview item to open a option menu and delete the "comment" with a click on an option menu entry. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Then every time someone clicks one of the items in the adapter, add the position of the item to an ArrayList, and when the delete menu option is pressed, delete all the comment's indexes in the adapter.